# Sklearn Nearest Neighbors and unseen data

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, collaborative-filtering

I've used Nearest Neighbors to find closely related customers in order to recommend popular products to a target customer.  I've fit a sparse matrix of training users to get the cosine distances.  However, I cannot get indices and distances of new users on the fitted model because those users aren't in the original matrix.  Is there a way around this, or do I have to refit the model each time new users are introduced?

Thanks!!

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
train_df = train.pivot(index = 'user', columns = 'product_id', values = 'rating').fillna(0)
test_df = test.pivot(index = 'user', columns = 'product_id', values = 'rating').fillna(0)
train_mat = csr_matrix(train_df.values)
test_mat = csr_matrix(test_df.values)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric = 'cosine', algorithm = 'brute', n_neighbors=30)
model_knn.fit(train_mat)

test_user = list(np.sort(test_df.user.unique())) 

list1=[]
query_index = np.random.choice(test_user)
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(test_df.loc[query_index, :].values.reshape(1, -1))
for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):
    list1.append(test_df.index[indices.flatten()[i]])
```

Here is the error message:

```
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 1605 while Y.shape[1] == 2724
```

Comment: This feels broad. It's unclear to me if you are talking about the *cold-start problem* or just about using APIs of used software. In the latter, we probably need to see code.

Comment: thanks @sascha.  my apologies that is is unclear.  just edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors) it states:

```
Returns:
dist : array
    Array representing the lengths to points, only present if return_distance=True
```

So you can try:

```
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors( 
    test_df.loc[query_index,:].values.reshape(1, -1), 
    return_distance=True
  )
```